# Program stops without error on struct member assignment

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment

I have a function which accepts a pointer to a struct and sets a member of that struct to a specific value. However, after that assignment code is executed, and my program exits without showing any errors.

```
void swn_addClassToInstance(struct instanceR *instance)
{
 instance->classCount = 0;
 //nothing below here will run
}
```

I'm new to C, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, the likely culprit is that `instance` doesn't point anywhere meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probable cause is that `instance` is NULL or not initialized, thus causing an access violation. It would be help if you show the code where you allocate and initialize the memory for the struct `instance` points to.

Comment: It turns out my struct wasn't being assigned properly. Thanks.